# 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a Web API in VS 2015 Pro (Update 3) using C# and targeting .NET Core.

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#install-entity-framework).
However, I am connecting to a MySQL database instead of an SQL Server database - not sure how much difference that makes...

Anyway, in the tutorial, I have to *"Register my context with dependency injection"* - so I have to add the following line to the **ConfigureServices** section of the **Startup.cs** file:

```
var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext< Models.PropWorxContext > (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));;
```

However, VS gives me the following error:

*Error CS1061 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Any ideas why?

This is what the whole Startup.cs file looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace PropWorxAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext< Models.PropWorxContext > (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added the MySQL package using the Package Manager, so that my **project.json** file contains this entry:

```
*"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31"*
```

Any hints as to where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated, as I've spent all day trying to figure it out :( Thank you...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

SqlServer is Microsoft Sql Server not MySql, to use SqlServer you would need the package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.*".

If using MySql there is options.UseMySql

see this [tutorial for more](https://damienbod.com/2016/08/26/asp-net-core-1-0-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-core/)

Answer (score 15):

I got this error as well whilst setting up a project using Sql Server for a database. In my case I had to add a using statement manually - 
    "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" . It sounds a bit obvious but it threw me as Visual Studio wasn't adding the using statement via Quick Actions.

Answer (score 9):

If you have already installed the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" package and using Ctrl + Space cannot give you any option, adding the "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" manually solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

missing package.This worked for me.
tools-NUget package-package manager-copy paste following install:

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

While in your project folder type this into your command line:

```
dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -v 2.1.2
```

Answer (score -1):

Install Sqllite/Sqlserver compact toolbox then create database if not created then change connectionstring in appsettings.json