# Error CS1061 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition > for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer'

Tags: c#, dbcontext

Not sure which assembly I should reference to, to remove this blocking error.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<QAContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

> Error CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
>   for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: type the following in Google Search `C# CS1061 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342137/dbcontextoptionsbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-usesqlserver)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using EntityFrameworkCore you must:

Add to Reference:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Add to source file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Answer (score 3):

First go to toolbar > Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console, And it will be open below
type "Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"
and it will solved.